# Windows 8 - Threading Error when async awaiting in For loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to load saved data in my Windows 8 app. All methods are asynchronous. When `await GetStoredActivitiesInFolder(groupFolder);` runs in the for loop for the second time I get an error because the thread is still processing the first one (I guess).

The error (it's gone when I remove the above line of code):

> An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The application called an interface that was
>   marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E
>   (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

My code:

```
 public async void LoadActivities()
    {
        StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        StorageFolder activityFolder = await storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync(App.AppSettings.ActivityDirectory, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> groupFolders = await activityFolder.GetFoldersAsync();

        ObservableCollection<ActivityDataGroup> groups = new ObservableCollection<ActivityDataGroup>();

        foreach (var groupFolder in groupFolders)
        {
            ActivityDataGroup group = new ActivityDataGroup();
            group.GroupName = groupFolder.Name;

            ICollection<ActivityViewModel>  activities = await GetStoredActivitiesInFolder(groupFolder);

            foreach (var activity in activities)
            {
                group.Items.Add(activity);
            }

            AllGroups.Add(group);

        }

        this.IsDataLoaded = true;
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `GetStoredActivitiesInFolder`?

Comment: This kind of error can happen if you're using one of the `ForCurrentView` objects from an old view. Could you post the code to `GetStoredActivitiesInFolder`? BTW, avoid `async void`; use `async Task` instead.

Comment: In most cases async Task is better since you can await the call, but there are times you don't care and want to do a fire and forget one. For example if you call an async method from a constructor you can't await it anyway.

Comment: GetStoredActivitiesInFolder returns a Task<ICollection<ActivityViewModel>> (so ICollection<ActivityViewModel> when used async).

Comment: That function also uses an await FileIO.ReadTextAsync function

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible your GetStoredActivitiesInFolder returns on a non-UI thread, then you could either modify it so it doesn't or do something like this to make sure you update the view-bound items on a UI thread, e.g. like that:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(
    CoreDispatcherPriority.High,
    () =>
    {
        AllGroups.Add(group);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked, but I randomly found it out. The LoadActivities function was called in the constructor of a page. When I moved it to the OnLaunched method it magically worked. I have no idea why but it did. =)

Anyway, thanks for the help, sorry to bother.